# Error when run schedule tasks every minute in Laravel 5.8 in Laradock with workspace

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, schedule

I created command

```
php artisan notification:update_status
```

I added into Schedule tasks every minute ==> error:

```
could not find driver
```

I run

```
php artisan notification:update_status
```

and

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

it  okay.

I don't understand why run schedule tasks every minute not work. I using postgresql and laravel 5.8

Sorry for my english. Please help me (:

Comment: Install the required driver on your server.

Comment: I using laradock: ```nginx postgres```